# Handling Null value in asp.net and Oracle SQL

Tags: asp.net, webforms, odp.net

How can I handle null values?

I have an object like this:

```
public class Person {
public string codSeller = "";
}
```

Now when I want to make the insert into the DB, I add the parameter:

```
Function that insert that value to BD(aPerson)

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("PKG_TEST", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vCOD_SELLER", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(aPerson.codSeller);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

I know that this won't work, is there a way to insert an int oracle null value if the codSeller comes empty or null?
Taking in consideration that I have to convert that string to int32 and to check if it comes empty or null?

EDIT:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(aPerson.codSeller))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vCOD_SELLER", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("vCOD_SELLER", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(aPerson.codSelle);
        }
```

Comment: There are a lot of possible solutions. But start with Googling `IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks, I have found a way.

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(aPerson.codSeller))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("vCOD_SELLER", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("vCOD_SELLER", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(aPerson.codSeller);
                }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the codeSeller property as Nullable?

```
public class Person {
  public int? codSeller = null;
}
```

Comment: Would that kind of variable be easy to control when converting or parsing the value?

Comment: So Nullable int will allow you to store either null or integer value based on your requirement. You can parse the string to integer and store in nullable int.